# filled circle in table field

Tags: tables, matrices, fill, draw

At the moment I am using beamer and have a table in a frame:
Everything works fine except that where I put this color filled circle the table breaks apart but I want to have the circle just within the table field not the table left and right to it if you know what I mean.

```
\documentclass[leqno,8pt,fleqn,table]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\tikzset{
table/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes={
        rectangle,
        draw=black,
        align=center,
               },
                    %baseline={([yshift=-0.5ex]current bounding box.center)},
    minimum height=1.5em,
    text depth=0.5em,
    text height=1em,
            text centered,
    nodes in empty cells,
    %%
                            row 1/.style={
        nodes={
            fill=black,
            text=white,
            %font=\bfseries
        }
    },
            rows/.style={nodes={fill=gray!10}},
            columns/.style={nodes={text width = 10em}},
            %myrowstyle/.style={
                %row #1/.style={nodes={fill=gray!10}}
    %},
   }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tiny}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[table, rows={2,...,3}{fill=grey!10}, columns={1,...,5}{text width = 10em}, ampersand replacement=\&] (first)
    { 
        card \# \& date \& 1 \& 2 \& 3 \\
        ghul \& 01.01.2016 \& \fill[green] (1,0) circle (0.05); \& \fill[red] (1,0) circle (0.05); \& \fill[red] (1,0) circle (0.05); \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tiny}
%\vspace{4mm}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/table'.

Comment: u missing this?:

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you want green and red circles, inside  `(first-2-3)`, `(first-2-4)` and `(first-2-5)`. where `2` represents row number and `3,4,5` columns numbers inside `first` matrix, here a solution

```
\documentclass[leqno,8pt,fleqn,table]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shadings}

\def\r{0.1}

\tikzset{
    table/.style={
        matrix of nodes,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={
            rectangle,
            draw=black,
            align=center,
                   },
                        %baseline={([yshift=-0.5ex]current bounding box.center)},
        minimum height=1.5em,
        text depth=0.5em,
        text height=1em,
                text centered,
        nodes in empty cells,
%%
                                row 1/.style={
            nodes={
                fill=black,
                text=white,
                %font=\bfseries
            }
        },
                rows/.style={nodes={fill=gray!10}},
                columns/.style={nodes={text width = 10em}},
                %myrowstyle/.style={
                    %row #1/.style={nodes={fill=gray!10}}
        %},
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tiny}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[table, rows={2,...,3}{fill=grey!10}, columns={1,...,5}{text width = 10em}, ampersand replacement=\&] (first)
    { 
        card \# \& date \& 1 \& 2 \& 3 \\
        ghul \& 01.01.2016 \&  \&  \&  \\
};

\fill[left color=green,right color=red] (first-2-3) circle (\r);
\fill[red] (first-2-4) circle (\r);
\fill[red] (first-2-5) circle (\r);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tiny}
%\vspace{4mm}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thats cool Thank you very much. Simple and quick :-)
Just two questions: Is it possible to do a half filled green red circle?
Like the left half of the circle is green and the right half is red. 
Also is it possible to write the circle diameter/radius (0.05 in this case) within a variable like in some language:
r=0.05 so I could change it in one go and not in every line.

Comment: Answer updated, you can define a command which reserve the circle radius `\def\r{0.1}`,  for two colors fill you can take advantage of the `shadings` library.

Comment: Hey again Thx, why do I need to specify the shadings library since (at least for me) it also works without...

Comment: Though why doesnt this left/right color option work with \shade ball:
\shade[ball, left color=green, right color=red] (first-2-3) circle (\r);
does not work

Comment: No  `left color` and `right color` key for `ball`.

Comment: Any other fancy "balls" they work with?

Comment: Hello Again,
I didnt want to open a new Thread because it actually belongs here!
How do I place the circle in the field specifically at a certain position?
Likewise if I have a Text in a Field I want the circle to be immediately infront of the Text.
I tried to do: \fill[green] (0,0) circle (0.1);
inside a field but this gives me an error "no shape named TabA1-2-3 is known"

Comment: Actually this works at least:
`\fill[green] (TabA1-2-3) (1,0) circle (0.1) ;`
but it is kinda awkward to position the circle properly, since it doesnt even reference to the position in the field, but to the center of the whole table...
 Is it possible to place a marker at the point in the table where the dot is supposed to appear and then reference to that marker similar to the additional entry (0,0) ???

Comment: @Diger Please ask a follow-up question, with a minimal working example and a link to this question, if you have a new but related question. Questions should be questions and hiding them in comments just makes it hard for other users to find them. If they get answered, it gets worse, because the answers no longer address the question asked. I would suggest accepting this answer and asking a new question, linking to this one. New related questions don't 'belong here' - they belong in question spaces of their own.

Comment: This is very sad and I will then ask a new question next week when I have access to a proper computer. But let me just recapitulate: The first question was on how to put a circle in a matrix field and my follow up question ist how to put a circle in a matrix field at a specific position. I fail to see how this is worth a new question and not a follow up. But it is good to know about the bounty i didnt know of before somebody in the other post brought it up.

Comment: In view of the fact that the solution above only needs minor modification most likely dont u think its worth not to just post it here.