# Question about positioning of a body in TIKZ in a matrix field

Tags: tikz-pgf

I had a new question about an old issue, so I did not see any sense in making a completely new post with basically the same content, so I just make a new post in order to push this to the top as new question so more ppl see it. The new question is a comment below the answer in
[filled circle in table field](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313864/filled-circle-in-table-field)

Thanks for help.

Comment: But you got already an answer on the old question, and I fail to see what's wrong with it. How can anyone answer your question without this information. As far as I can see, Salim Bou answered your question and even accommodated additional requests that you made later. So I think you should accept his answer and ask a new question for the additional features you have in mind. BTW, the official way to push a question up the queue is to offer a bounty, not to just post a "new" question with a link to the old one.

Comment: This is not what new posts are for. There is no question here and nothing to answer. Insofar as there is, this is just a duplicate of your existing question.